# How can I match a set of characters which appear in any order and at most once?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a very, very basic parser for a thing, and as part if it, I decided to use regular expressions to find regular expressions.

This is what regular expressions will look like:

```
r/pattern/flags
```

except that `/` can be any of `` /|:!`. ``. That's so that you can, for example, match URLs without lots of `\/`s. Now, this is what I have so far:

```
r([\/|:!`.])(.*?)(?<![^\\]\\)\1x?m?i?g?a?s?
```

However, this has a problem: it doesn't match `r/abcde/ai`. Given that the flags should be able to be specified in any order, this fails. I've also tried this:

```
r([\/|:!`.])(.*?)(?<![^\\]\\)\1([xmigas]+)
```

But this has the problem that it allows `r|abc|aaaasxmaaaiisggss`, which it shouldn't. If I limit it to `[xmigas]{,6}` I can still write `|iiiii`.

Now, I realize I can do something very long and complicated but that would be impossible to scale so I'd rather avoid it. Is there any way to match a set of characters which can appear at most once, and in any order, without anything complicated?

In this specific case, I'm using Ruby, and I'm fine with adding gems if necessary. I might also be able to switch languages, though it'd be a lot of work and I'd much rather not.

<sup>This is a personal project, meant to be for fun. Please ignore how bad the idea of searching for regex with regex is.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) should do what you want. I'm going to neglect everything except the flag-matching part, for simplicity.

Consider the following:

```
(?:([xmigas])(?!.*\1.*))*
```

We look for a valid flag letter, but we assert that the content following this flag letter does not contain the same flag letter again. We then repeat the whole thing 0 or more times (and let the lookaheads implicitly prevent any extra flags from existing).

Comment: But you explained the technique you used instead of just saying "this works".

Comment: Also: I think this regex get sconsiderably more complicated if you take away the restriction that the flags are at the end of the string.

Comment: yeah, I was just focused on giving the answer first, so that I could edit the explanation later :) kudos to you

Comment: Well. good answer -- covers what I wanted and explains it as well. Thanks a ton! The flags are guaranteed to be at the end of the string by the way I'm parsing it, as it happens.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what complications arise if it's not at the end of the string?

Comment: Well, look at the condition that's used in the lookahead. It requires the matched flag to exist nowhere in the remainder of the string. If there was other (not flag) content later on, we'd need to restrict the region that regex searches. We'd have to have a more complicated regex in the condition that looks for "no repetitions until the end of the flags" instead of "no repetitions ever".

Comment: It wouldn't be too horrible, to be honest, especially if the language your parsing has a nice separator you can look for. I didn't think about it too closely :P

Comment: @ChrisKitching So... add `\b` to the end of it? Assuming the flags are all in `\w`.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes It depends what comes after the flags. If the next thing after the flags counts as a word boundary, yes.

Comment: @ChrisKitching In this case, tokens are separated by whitespace, so that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This matches all combinations of x,m,i,g,a,s without duplicates:

```
^(?:([xmigas])(?!.*\1))*$
```

So particularly in your case, the expression would be

```
/^r([\/|:!`.])(.*?)\1(?:([xmigas])(?!.*\3))*$/
```

See it in action [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/YWsfhwuHDc)

Also, see @Chris's answer for details